# Are the books written by Irulan in Paul of Dune meant to represent the books quoted in Frank Herbert’s 1965 version of Dune?

Tags: dune, frank-herbert, brian-herbert, kevin-j-anderson

In the Brian Herbert and Kevin Anderson works Princess Irulan writes *The Life of Muad’Dib, Volume 1-3*. Are these meant to be the original Frank Herbert trilogy - *Dune*, *Dune Messiah*, and *Children of Dune*?

From *Paul of Dune*:

> Thwarted in her primary goal, Irulan  followed instead the basic tenet of the Sisterhood: adapt or die. Thus she had worked to find a new function for herself in the government, and quickly achieved her own fame by publishing *The Life of Muad’Dib, Volume 1*. It was rapidly written, swiftly published and distributed, and wildly popular. Most of Paul’s Fremen warriors carried well- read copies of her book.

And later in the same chapter something that feels like a first version of the litany against fear?

> “This is a raped and pillaged corpse of what was once the grandest of cities. It will never be the same.”
>
> Paul could not deny her statement. “Wherever Muad’Dib goes, nothing is the same again. Didn’t you write that in your book?”
>
> “I wrote the story you told me. As I interpreted it, of course.”

As another piece of evidence, *The Life of Muad’Dib* does not appear in any chapter epigraphs, based on the [Fandom](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Irulan_Corrino%27s_Attributed_Book_Workings) entry. And the first epigraph from Chapter 1 of Dune includes a reference to “the life of Muad’Dib”:

> *A beginning is the time for taking the most delicate care that the balances are correct. This every sister of the Bene Gesserit knows. To begin your study of the life of Muad’Dib, then, take care that you first place him in his time: born in the 57th year of the Padishah Emperor, Shaddam IV. And take the most special care that you locate Muad’Dib in his place: the planet Arrakis. Do not be deceived by the fact that he was born on Caladan and lived his first fifteen years there. Arrakis, the planet known as Dune, is forever his place.*
>
> *– from “Manual of Muad’Dib” by the Princess Irulan*

There is also an old post on [jacurutu](http://www.jacurutu.com/viewtopic.php?t=2823) that references the intention to make the original Dune book by Frank Herbert the Life of Muad’Dib, but I do not know if that is a real reference or just speculation.

Comment: Your second quote is nothing like the litany against fear. How are you interpreting it?

Comment: I always assumed they were books written by Irulan in universe, there were many quotes from them at the beginning of chapters. Her works seem to contain a lot of propaganda.

Comment: I always understood "To begin your study of the life of Muad’Dib, " to mean studying the history of the life of the man. Not a reference to a book. It has no capital letters as the title of the book would.

Comment: Seemed like a retro-fit by Bryan Herbert to me, but I may be proven wrong.

Comment: So you think that the book Dune was written by Princess Irulan. And inside of that book she quotes herself? ....

Comment: @Darren Muad'Dib is the fear.

Comment: Total stretch. Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: I think it’s clear that Irulan is a potential narrator, @Questor: https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Discrepancies_between_Dune_novels “Though theories of different Duniverse narrators are outside of the scope of this article, potential narrators may include Irulan Corrino, Paul Atreides, Leto Atreides II, Duncan Idaho, Siona Atreides, the Oracle of Time, Daniel and Marty, and Erasmus.” - maybe I should change the question to ask which of these are the narrator, but I believe Kevin Anderson said the Dune books were written by Irulan as propaganda in an interview but I can’t find it.

Comment: Ah, found the justification- it’s the fact that the book Dune talks about Paul never being offworld but then later books contradict this - you can find the detail under “Paul of Dune” here: http://www.jacurutu.com/viewtopic.php?t=1538